# Why Mathematica 13.1 shuts down completely when printing to console but not to the notebook?

Tags: front-end, crash, printing

reported to WRI. **ID [CASE:4950759]**

---

I just found a very serious problem in V 13.1. Hoping someone will have a workaround.

I am able to reproduce this each time. V 13.1 on windows 10 pro. All from fresh new Mathematica session started new.

`Integrate` is called with timeout. Then the result is printed.

When print is directed to console, All of Mathematica shutdown (I do not mean kernel dies, but I mean all of Mathematica dies. The front end, all of it just closes). No error message, nothing. It just disappears from the screen.

When print is directed to the notebook, it works !  No crash.

Here is the code below. I also put a link to the notebook at the end.

Please make sure to **SAVE** all your work before trying this.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToConsole"}
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"MessageOptions", "KernelMessageAction"}] = {"PrintToConsole", "Beep"}

integrand = Sqrt[a + b*Sin[e + f*x]]*Sqrt[c + d*Sin[e + f*x]];
Print["Before calling integrate on ", integrand];
res = AbsoluteTiming[ TimeConstrained[Integrate[integrand, x], 60*3]];
Print["Done! "];
(*Mathematica shuts down when issuing this command*)
Print[res]
```

Now replacing the above with

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook"}
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"MessageOptions", "KernelMessageAction"}] = {"PrintToNotebook", "Beep"}
```

With the rest of the code same, Then it works and **no crash**

The question is: Why does this happen and is there a workaround? This never happened in 13.01.

Here is a movie

[image]

Here is also a [link](https://12000.org/tmp/07052022/BUG_13_1.nb) to the notebook

Comment: Wow! Definitely needs a report sent to tech support.

Comment: @CATrevillian I did. Was just waiting to get the CASE ID in email to post it. Thanks, I got it just now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's simply a bug report.

Comment: No crash on "13.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Comment: Why is your window title font size so big?